# Ember setupController request

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-router

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.store.findAll('podcast')
  },
  setupController(controller, model){
    model.forEach(function(v){
      //i want to make a request here
    })
    controller.set('model', model)
  }
});
```

`this.store.findAll('podcast')` returns URLs to podcast feeds. I want to make a request in `setupController` to get the `/feed` from URLs. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure just use native jQuery AJAX calls. Something like this:

**Route**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.findAll('podcast')
    },

    setupController(controller, model) {
        controller.set('podcastFeeds', []);

        model.forEach( podcast => {
            Ember.$.ajax({
                url: podcast.get('feed'), // get the property
            }).then( feedData => {
                controller.get('podcastFeeds').addObject(feedData);
            }, () => {
                //handle error
            });
        });
    }
});
```

**Template**

```
{{#each podcastFeeds as |podcastFeed|}}
    {{{podcastFeed}}}
{{/each}}
```